# Service Response Time gradually increasing in IE 11 of angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-11

I have a problem with working angular is in IE 11. 
I call a service from IE 11, Service Response time gradually increasing. First time, it's take 1 second. second time I call same service, it's take 2 second, then 4 Sec, then 5 Sec then after 5-6 times call then response time is near about 20 Sec.
Something not happening in Chrome or Mozilla Firefox. There are working in perfect.

Please help me some solution, thanks.
[image: First call service in IE][image: After 5 times response time in IE][image: Response Time in Chrome]